# How do I move the onclik text to move to the text area?

Tags: javascript, html

how when i click apple

Apple's text area, not the number.

```js
function getIndex() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="getIndex()" value="Display the index of the selected option">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I compile the value in the select option, I want the text to come out instead of the number

Comment: Replace `.selectedIndex` with `.value` (an option without dedicated `value` receives its textual content as value, and a select's value is that of the selected option)

Comment: @yuda, Your question is not clear. What is your problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line `document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;` with `document.getElementById("mySelect").value;`

Answer (score 1):

Get the selected index and get the corresponding option's value using `option[index].text`

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function getIndex() {

      var index = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("mySelect").options[index].text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" onclick="getIndex()" value="Display the index of the selected option">
  <p id="demo"></p>
```